# knockoutjs execute callback immediately after subscribe to observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have:

```
    this.selectedItem.subscribe(model => {
        this.currentEditor(this.editors.find(e => e.canRender(model)));
        this.currentEditor().render(model);
    });
```

where `this.selectedItem` already has a value.

Is it possible to run callback (but leaving it anonymous) immediately after subscribing?

Comment: You can call `valueHasMutated` on `this.selectedItem`. So `this.selectedItem.valueHasMutated()` however this not just runs your callback but also notify everybody else, e.g bindings, computeds etc. So you are propably better to have a named function and call it when it is needed and use that in the `subscribe`

Comment: @nemesv, in my opinion your comment is pretty much a full answer, and I would upvote it if it was. Consider re-posting as an answer.

Comment: @nemesv, thanks. Please, convert your comment to the answer in order to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `valueHasMutated` on `this.selectedItem`, so

```
this.selectedItem.valueHasMutated()
```

**However this not just runs your callback but also notify everybody else**, e.g bindings, computeds etc.

So you are propably better to have a named function and call it when it is needed and use that also in the subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract function into a variable and call it:

```
var changeHandler = (model) => {
    this.currentEditor(this.editors.find(e => e.canRender(model)));
    this.currentEditor().render(model);
};
this.selectedItem.subscribe(changeHandler);
changeHandler();
```

Comment: The question is how to avoid extracting variable. afaik RX in C# allows it (by passing additional parameter)